# Update Angular dropdown after insert and select new value

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular and was wondering how I can update a dropdown after doing an insert and have the new value selected?

I tried the following:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCompany" ng-change="GetCompany()"
        ng-options="company.key as company.value for company in CompanyList">
     <option value="">Select a Company</option>
</select>
```

This populates a list of companies when the page 1st loads and the inserted data is returned to scope + it's id.

To add the new value without refreshing the page, I'm trying the following non-working (almost) code:

```
var key = $scope.company.id;
var value = $scope.company.name;

$scope.CompanyList.push({ key: value });

$scope.selectedCompany = $scope.company.id;
```

This seems to add a value to the dropdown, but it's showing up blank.  It's also not selecting the blank value (which should be the new company name), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yup, `({ key: value })` ==> `({ key: key, value: value })`

Comment: That did it, thanks, post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Give me a minute, i'll write a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so what do we have here?

You're creating your options with the [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive like this: `ng-options="company.key as company.value for company in CompanyList"`

That mean that the array `$scope.CompanyList` must have objects with a `key` property that will be set to the option `value` attribute, and a `value` that will be the option *display value* (Or *label*, if you prefer to call it that way).

**What you were doing wrong:** You added an object with only one property named `key` and set its value with the `value` variable: `$scope.CompanyList.push({ key: value });`

**How should you fix it:** You need to append object(s) with a `key` and a `value` like so: `$scope.CompanyList.push({ key: key, value: value });`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that when you create the new company object, you need to assign the `value` property which is the display name.
Here's a code snippet:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("testCtrl", function() {
    this.companyList = [{
      key: 1,
      value: "Company A"
    }];
    var ctrl = this;
    this.addCompany = function() {
      ctrl.companyList.push({key:2, value:"Company B"});
      ctrl.selectedCompany = 2;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" 
      ng-model="ctrl.selectedCompany" 
      ng-options="company.key as company.value for company in ctrl.companyList">
        <option value="" disabled>Select a Company</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.addCompany()">
      Add company B and select it
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice answer too! Only as a suggestion - You might want to save a reference to `this` and use it when you want to reference to the controller members (`var vm = this; vm.addCompany = function() { vm.selectedCompany = 2; }`

Comment: Nice catch @AlonEitan, I'm using too much TypeScript I guess.

Comment: Perhaps you are :) But very well-thought answer anyway

Comment: Yep, a lot of the code I have that I didn't post looks like what you posted :) So this is a more complete example of Alon's answer for reference purposes, not a fan of the hard coded values though.  I'm still up in the air on using scope vs this, but that's off topic here, When Angular 2 matures, I suppose I can do a find replace and fix my resulting errors :)

Comment: @RandomUs1r I have no problem with you selecting this answer instead, so you're welcome to do so

Comment: Hey @RandomUs1r, I'd strongly recommend you check out the ControllerAs syntax, since it has solved (and prevented) lot's of issues regarding scope inheritance. No one likes hard-codded values, but since this is a sample I don't dislike them so much.

Comment: Personally, I like more @AlonEitan answer since it has a better explanation of the issue. Happy coding guys!

Answer (score 1):

The following line push an object, which has a property name "key" set to `value`:

```
$scope.CompanyList.push({ key: value });
```

The result will be:

```
{'key': $scope.company.name}
```

You may change it to:

```
$scope.CompanyList.push({key: key, value: value});
```

Which will result in:

```
{ 'key': $scope.company.id, 'value': $scope.company.name }
```